# error converting array to string

Tags: java, arrays

so my program prints an array but when it does it also includes brackets and commas and i dont want those.

here is my library

```
import java.util.*;
public class library2
{
        public static boolean IsPrime(int p)
        {
                for (int i = 2; i < p; i++)
                {
                        if (p % i == 0 && i != p)
                                return false;
                }
                return true;
        }
        public static List<List<Integer>> GetPrimes(int n)
        {
                List<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                for (int j = 2; j < n; j++)
                {
                        if(IsPrime(j))
                        {
                                arr.add(j);
                        }
                }
                return Arrays.asList(arr);
        }
}
```

here is my driver

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class driver2
{
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
                Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.print("Please input an integer: ");
                int n = scan.nextInt();
                Boolean check = library2.IsPrime(n);
                List<List<Integer>> arr = library2.GetPrimes(n);
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
        }
}
```

ive tried the `Arrays.toString();` method but i get an error when i compile. i used `import java.util.Arrays;` but that didnt solve anything. can someone help me out.

Comment: So how do you want your output formatted?

Comment: instead of [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]] which i get, i want 1 2 3 4 5

Comment: OK. Then write your code to do just that.

Comment: Why in the first place do you need  `List<List<Integer>>` when you can do it with `List<Integer>`

Answer (score 1):

`arr` is a list and not an array.

You should iterate over and print:

```
     Iterator<List<Integer>>  arrIterator = arr.iterator(); 
     while (arrIterator.hasNext()) {
        List<Integer> l = arrIterator.next();
        Iterator<Integer> lIterator = l.iterator(); 
        while(lIterator.hasNext()){
          int i = lIterator.next();     
          System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
```

Comment: would i place this in my library or my driver

Comment: `hasNext()` is a method of `Iterator` and not the list itself.

Comment: thank you but can you explain why my <Arrays.toString(arr));> didnt work

Comment: Because your `arr` is not an array, its a list.

Comment: And now you can (if you wish to) use *syntactic sugar* and re-write it using `for-each` loops.